# How can I copy files from a folder into multiple folders

Tags: python, directory, shutil

I have 130 files in a folder source and I want to copy each files in a single folder 001, 002, 003 ... 130 (all these 130 folders are located in destination folder).

So that every folder contain just one file.
I came up with this but probably it's a bit messy and redundant... and mostly it doesn't work.

```
import shutil
import os

source = '/Users/JohnCN/photo_database/mugshot_frontal/'
files = os.listdir(source)

for i in files:

    for fold in range(1,131):

        if fold<10:
            destination = "/Users/JohnCN/photo_DBsorted/00%s" %fold
            shutil.move(source+i, destination)

        elif fold in range(10,100):
            destination = "/Users/JohnCN/photo_DBsorted/0%s" %fold
            shutil.move(source+i, destination)

        else:
            destination = "/Users/JohnCN/photo_DBsorted/%s" %fold
            shutil.move(source+i, destination)
```

Comment: are you using python2?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.6.7

Comment: strings formatting you've used in this question are usually used for python2, though it is not deprecated for python3. 
Since 3.6 version of Python there is available f-string formatting, that looks more convenient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it the following way:

```
import shutil
import os

source = '/Users/JohnCN/photo_database/mugshot_frontal/'
files = os.listdir(source)

for idx, f in enumerate(files):
    destination = '/Users/JohnCN/photo_DBsorted/{d:03d}'.format(d=(idx + 1))
    shutil.move(source + f, destination)
```

So, what does it do?
`for idx, f in enumerate(files):` counts the files while looping, so you know the index of the file. To get the destination, the idx is used as directory name. I assume you know the method `format`, `{d:03d}` simply says, that the value d is assigned to should be 3 characters long, the value is an integer and it's padded with zeros (e.g. 003). Of course, this code assumes that you do not have 1000+ files, in that case, just increase the number of zeroes. You could for example calculate the `log10`-value of the number of files to get the number of zeros you have to add.

Comment: thanks! Your explanation was really clear.                                                      
I have another question for you: I want to copy files from another source folder. This time for each person I have 6 photos ( for example for first person is 001_L1, 001_L2, 001_L3, 001_R1, 001_R2, 001_R3).        
How can I modify it so during each iteration it copies all this 6 photo in the right destination folder?

Comment: @EdoardoAb How are those photos arranged? Does every person already have an own folder? Is it guaranteed, that `os.listdir` gives the photos like `[PersonA_1, PersonA_2,...,PersonA_6,PersonB_1,...`]?

Comment: Yes, I would use the same folders I already used before (001,002,003 ... 130). yes, The photos in the source folder are arranged in a way that  `os.listdir` gives: `[001_L1.jpg, 001_L2.jpg, 001_L3.jpg, 001_R1.jpg, 001_R2.jpg, 001_R3.jpg, 002_L1.jpg, 002_L2.jpg, 002_L3.jpg, 002_R1.jpg, 002_R2.jpg, 002_R3.jpg ...]`

Comment: Ah, I think now I understand. Am I right that the names already are `001_L1, 001_L2,...` and that you just want to copy them to the folders `001,002,003,...` depending on the first number? In this case, you just have to split the name of the file using `f.split('_')` and the directory will be the first part of it, i.e. `target_dir = f.split('_')[0]`.

Comment: thanks! is it also correct to add this condition `substring = '{d:03d}'.format(d=(idx + 1)); if substring in f:` within the for cicle to obtain the same result?

Comment: It will work as long as `os.listdir` returns them in the same order. If for any reason the order would not be correct anymore, that check won't work. But the solution above doesn't need any such check, so I don't know why you would do that.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I would rather use `shutil.copy` if I wanted to copy the files, but not to move. Though, the main idea does not depend on it. Also you don't need no `if` statements here as well as the inner cycle:

```
files = os.listdir(source)

for i in range(len(files)):
    file = os.path.join(source, files[i]) 
    shutil.copy(file, os.path.join(source, '%03d'%i, files[i])
```

Comment: You were faster :(